# How to ensure that AF_PACKET socket doesn't get packets from other interfaces between socket and bind?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, posix

Consider an application that opens AF_PACKET socket to listen for packets on a specific interface.

The canonical way to do it is:

1. Open a socket
2. Bind it to the interface

The code may be like (error checks omitted for conciseness):

```
int sock_fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));

struct sockaddr_ll sock_addr = {
    .sll_family = AF_PACKET,
    .sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("ethXYZ"),
};
bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr);
```

Now, considering that network traffic may be high-rate and/or the executing thread may be preempted between socket and bind syscalls, it could happen that before binding, the socket buffer already received packets, possibly from other interfaces.

This is as defined in [packet(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html):

> By default, all packets of the specified protocol type are passed to a
> packet socket.  To get packets only from a specific interface use
> bind(2) specifying an address in a struct sockaddr_ll to bind the
> packet socket to an interface.  Fields used for binding are sll_family
> (should be AF_PACKET), sll_protocol, and sll_ifindex.

What will be the way to ensure that socket buffer is not populated with unwanted packets between socket and bind?

I've attempted two solutions so far:

1. After calling bind, set temporary drop-all sock filter, flush socket, disable sock filter
2. Use (undocummented?) third parameter `protocol = 0` in socket() call to drop packets unless bind is called (now, with non-zero protocol).

The simplified code for first solution is:

```
setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &fprog, sizeof(fprog));
while (1) {
    bytes = recv(sock_fd, buffer, buffer_size, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if (bytes == -1) // should check errno
            break;
}
setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DETACH_FILTER, &fprog, sizeof(fprog));
```

The second solution seems most elegant, since bind can provide both ethertype and interface index at the same time, but it seems like undefined behavior. Looking into [net/packet/af_packet.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/packet/af_packet.c#L3301), within `packet_create`, `proto` is being used for hooks, but not validated before (i.e. no error is returned):

```
if (proto) {
    po->prot_hook.type = proto;
    __register_prot_hook(sk);
}
```

Comment: You say you have attempted both solutions, does the second one work for you? If so, what's your kernel version (`uname -r`)? Looking at the kernel code it seems like `packet_do_bind()` in `net/packet/af_packet.c` should bail out before attaching the protocol hook when `protocol = 0`, but I might be looking at a different version than yours.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Yes, this confirms my doubts that this behavior may be undefined. Kernel version is `5.10.0-10-amd64`. Call to `socket` is with 0 protocol and `bind` is with `htons(ETH_P_ALL)` as the protocol.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, got confused by the code, `packet_do_bind()` does indeed bail out when `protocol = 0`, but of course you are doing `bind` with some `protocol != 0` so it does actually attach the protocol hook. It's a shame that creating a socket with protocol `0` is not documented, but it seems that your assumption holds and you can indeed create a "quiescent" socket with `protocol = 0` and then "activate" it when binding. I looked at 5.16, 5.10, 4.20, 4.10, 3.16, 3.0, 2.16.5 and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1):

After looking up into kernel code of [`af_packet.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/packet/af_packet.c), it seems like the method of creating a socket with 0 protocol should work fine.

While debugging, protocol func `packet_rcv` is never entered between socket and bind, thus such packets don't increase socket buffer, meaning `sk_rmem_alloc` is 0. After bind, new packets are entered and fill the buffer as expected, allocating and filling `sk_buff`:

```
[  548.455055] Called packet_rcv() pkt_type = 1
[  548.455058] packet_rcv() skb->len = 60
[  548.455059] packet_rcv() orig = 3, dev = 3
[  548.455060] packet_rcv() sk_rmem_alloc = 0

[  554.702140] Called packet_rcv() pkt_type = 1
[  554.702156] packet_rcv() skb->len = 60
[  554.702157] packet_rcv() orig = 3, dev = 3
[  554.702158] packet_rcv() sk_rmem_alloc = 768
```

The key point is that with `proto = 0`, the `packet_create()` won't call [`dev_add_pack`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/networking/API-dev-add-pack.html), thus `packet_rcv()` protocol handler won't be added into network stack until `bind()` is called.

Comment: I thought we came to this conclusion in the comment section under your answer, what made you change your mind and consider it ok even if undocumented? (No trying to say that it isn't, I'd say it's pretty safe to rely on it since the 1st rule on Linux is "never break userspace" and a lot of other programs are probably already relying on this too).

Comment: @Marco Bonelli: It's true, my intent was to add sort of analyze of kernel's code to cover it better. Hopefully, it's gonna be documented, since it seems rather clear to work well.

Comment: This behaviour is now documented in packet(7)